# How to list all the tags, on a remote, that reference a commit or one of its descendants?

Tags: git, tags, git-tag

How to list all the tags, on a remote, that reference a commit or one of its descendants?

I'm looking for something equivalent to `git branch -r --contains <commit>`, but for remote tags only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a single command that allows to get this result, but this process allows to resolve the issue. Consider that **ref_sha** is the hash of the commit for which you want to find the remote tags that reference it, or one of its descendants.

The tags present on the remote can be listed with the following command.

```
git ls-remote --tags
```

Each line of the output will represent a tag. A line starts with the hash of the pointed object and is followed by the tag path. If a tag points to an annotated tag object, a second line will be added. The tag path will be followed by ^{} and the hash will be that of the object obtained by recursively dereferencing the hash of the previous line.

Now, we need to fetch because we will need to perform ancestry checks.

```
git fetch
```

Now, for every tag listed in the first step, we need to make an ancestry check with the command below. Let **rem_sha** be the hash pointed by the tag. If the tag pointed to a tag object, you can use that hash or the recursively dereferenced object hash. If you provide the hash of an annotated tag object to the command, git will recursively dereference the tag automatically.

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <ref_sha> <rem_sha>
```

When this returns 0, it means that **rem_sha** is **ref_sha** or one of its descendants (equivalent to: **ref_sha** is **rem_sha** or an ancestor).

Note: we could not simply have  checked the local tags after fetching, because there may be local tags that haven't been pushed yet.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such thing as a "remote" tag. That is, you cannot differentiate between a tag that you only have locally and a tag that also or only exists on the remote.